# Custom Facebook feed - Like buttons

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've written out a custom facebook feed that uses the PHP SDK initially to get the data and then loops through the feed and prints it all out. Works fine with no problems.

I now need to add a like button to each feed, so I've done the below:

Within PHP Foreach Loop:

```
$ids = explode('_', $value['id']);
$like_it = "https://www.facebook.com/". $ids[0] ."/posts/". $ids[1] ?>

...

<fb:like href="<?php echo $like_it; ?>" layout="button_count" 
    show_faces="true" width="160" height="40"
    action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
```

I am loading the JS SDK asynchronously with correct App ID and XFBML enabled

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Now the like buttons display and do link to the news feed item they are assigned to as you would expect, though none of them pick up on the number of likes that are actually already attributed to the feed item. Strangely, one does... and I cant quite get my head round it.

Is there anything I am doing blatently wrong here?

[Here is the page in question](http://erebus.cashbackcard.com/blog) The like buttons have not been positioned properly yet as I'd rather get them working first!

Any help would be appreciated,

Cheers,
DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is not possible to do with Facebook any longer. There are other SO answers that go into detail on this topic and why this is not possible.